# Why do the length properties of arrays and strings have different return types?

Tags: typescript

```
type GetLength2<T extends any[]> = T['length']
type a = GetLength2<[1]> // 1

type GetLength3<T extends string> = T['length']
type e = GetLength3<'abc'> // number
```

The length property of an array returns a specific value, but the length property of a string returns a number type, why?

Comment: It's too bad you didn't ask how to calculate the length of a string literal, which you *can* do with template literal types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4RDN).  But that doesn't do anything to the type of the `length` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[1]` in `GetLength2<[1]>` is not just an array, it's a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). Tuples are special types that define the value at each index of the array, and also define the length of the array. Since tuples define the length, `GetLength2` gets that specific length. If you used a normal array instead of a tuple (eg, `GetLength2<number[]>`), the result would be `number`.

While strings do have some specialized variations at their disposal (eg, template string types), they don't have anything quite like tuples. The type `'abc'` does not include the information that the `length` property will return 3. Perhaps that's something they could add to the language in the future, but it's not there now.

Comment: You might want to refer to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34692 .