# Type to compute string length

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've come up with a solution to compute a `string`'s length.

I simply wonder if they're a better one, cause it seems a tad verbose ?

```
type LengthString <S extends string, L extends any [] = []> =
  S extends `${any}${infer Rest}`
    ? LengthString <Rest, [...L, any]>
    : L ['length']
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhB2BzYALAysATgSyVAPGlBAB7AIAmAzlFVrogDSzFmU0CG8IUA2gLpQAvH34A%20YQCgoUIqXLxqUAAYASAN5cQAXw24AZhExQAShDrbl0mVAD8sBMnT08%20M3Wa8AdD5jMt4tYyAFwsvADkADaOqOH8kpKgkFDkdMIOSKgYOK7hHABGAMbhEjYyAPTlUADMUBw0pJCF5BRAA)

Comment: There is no better way to do it. Feel free to stick with your solution

Comment: Btw, TypeScript is verbose, especially conditional types, so you better to get used to it :D

Comment: ^^ u just stole a laugh ;)

Comment: I doubt there's anything shorter, but do you care about edge cases?  Should `LengthString<string>` be `number`?  What about `LengthString<\`ab${string}cd\`>`?

Comment: @jcalz I've come up with [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhB2BzYALAysATgSyVAPGlBAB7AIAmAzlFVrogDSzFmU0CG8IUA2gLpQAvH34A+YQCgoUIqXLxqUAAYASAN64AZhExQAwig6YAvhu26oAJQh0Ty6TKgB+WvTzz2Bo3tfwArgC2AEaWAFywCMjo7ogENnTMvAB0qTDMXCDijjIRMHwA5AA2UagF-JKSoJBQ5HQADACMwpFIqBg4ePgFHMEAxgUSTsPDAPSjUADMUBw0pJB95BRV4NB1wPUATC1wbTGdcfjKvRp0ByZ9FMpD41ABIbpAA) do you have a better approach ?

Comment: I don't know, I made [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858363/why-do-the-length-properties-of-arrays-and-strings-have-different-return-types#comment125266552_70858363) a few days ago, to also try to take care of the presence of `\`${number}\``, which your version treat like a single character, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4qDN) in your version. But really, who knows the kind of edge cases that can happen?